# how to get only specific portion of text from the url using iPhone SDK?

Tags: iphone, html, objective-c, ios, xcode

In my app, i have a URL of some webpage & i want to get only specific part/portion from that URL(its html page) by identifying the html tags.

for example, i want to get portion as `<div id="content"> to </div>` as per html source code.
so that i can save it on another file.

**e.g. my url is** http://www.makepartsfast.com/2012/09/4337/more-3d-printing-in-metals-ex-one-introduces-the-m-flex-3d-printing-system/, which opens one html page. and i want only some portion of that page.

How can i do it?

Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the Cocoa+NSString solution (working + tested). You'll see that the only real trick when you use a custom parser like this, is how to find the "end" point. Indeed, you can't just go up to "" as other divs are opened in the middle, so your parser would stop before the end of what you're looking for. I clearly don't say there aren't other ways of doing this, with much more complex XML parsers. But web pages aren't so easy to parse, their code isn't always perfect...and this is simple and working (still you should consider an other way of getting the URL content than stringWithContentsOfURL: which isn't asynchronous):

```
NSString *originalString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.makepartsfast.com/2012/09/4337/more-3d-printing-in-metals-ex-one-introduces-the-m-flex-3d-printing-system/"] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:originalString];
NSString *extractedString = nil;

[scanner scanUpToString:@"<div id=\"content\">" intoString:nil];
[scanner scanString:@"<div id=\"content\">" intoString:nil];

[scanner scanUpToString:@"<div style=\"clear:both;\">" intoString:&extractedString];

if (extractedString) 
{
    // string was extracted
    NSLog(@"%@", extractedString);
}
```

Comment: can you be more specific please ? is it that you don't know how to get the page content into "originalString" ? the parsing itself works, I edit to show a very basic (should be improved for real life use) way of getting the content into originalString

Comment: how can i get only image URL from it?? and also show all parse data as a html page in uiwebview.

Comment: can you please already accept this as the answer to this question ? What you're asking is another question: you want to display HTML code in a UIWebView. Please use the search function here before, or look for UIWebView loadHTMLString:baseURL:

Answer (score 0):

Check the Tutorial [How to Parse HTML on iOS](http://www.raywenderlich.com/14172/how-to-parse-html-on-ios) from Raywenderlich.Hope this may help you.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/14172/how-to-parse-html-on-ios

Answer (score 0):

You can use an open source library GDataXMLNode. It allow you to manipulate xml files. Take a look at

http://www.raywenderlich.com/725/how-to-read-and-write-xml-documents-with-gdataxml
http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/source/browse/trunk/Source/XMLSupport/?r=129

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to use `NSXMLParser` to search for a `div` tag with an attribute `id` equal to "content". Capture all of the intermediate content until the appropriate `</div>` closing tag. See [Apple's tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/XMLParsing/XMLParsing.html).